# What is wrong with my redirect from old domain to new domain on the same Apache server?

Tags: apache

We are getting a new domain name for an app running as the only domain on a server.

So for this question lets say we are moving **olddomain.co.uk** to **newdomain.com**.  Both these domains will stay up for the first few months and although I didn't set it up myself I am pretty sure they are both recorded as 2 separate records against the same IP address.  For a couple of weeks I would like to get all requests to the new domain rewritten to the old domain and then I will swap it over for a few months.

So I can do this (at the bottom of httpd.conf)

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'newdomain.com'">
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.google.co.uk [L]
</If>
```

and this works perfectly except it is not the requirement.  olddomain.co.uk goes to the app and newdomain.com is redirected to google.

So my next step is to put in the rule I want to use

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'newdomain.com'">
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"  "http://oldmain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI}" 
</If>
```

This returns a generic error (apologies I forgot to record what error and need to wait a while before I can reproduce it - it being a live server - I'll add ths later with an edit if needs be).

I have a UAT environment but unfortunately it does not have a domain registered and is accessed using IP address.  I have had an org level dns mapping set up and have done some testing with this.  Until it failed on live I thought I had got this sussed.

So on UAT I had something like this

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'uatserver'">
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"  "http://[ipaddress]%{REQUEST_URI}" 
</If>
```

and this worked.

If I alter the live server to redirect to the uat server this works...

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'newdomain.com'">
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"  "http://[uat-ip-address]%{REQUEST_URI}" 
</If>
```

so there doesn't seem to be a problem with the syntax.

It **seems** that on the live server the issue is to do with it redirecting onto the same box (?)

The only real difference I can see between my UAT & Live servers is in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.  This is the live one

```
NameVirtualHost olddomain.co.uk 
NameVirtualHost newdomain.com
NameVirtualHost [ip address]

<VirtualHost [ip address] olddomain.co.uk newdomain.com localhost:80>

    serveralias [ip address]
    serveralias olddomain.co.uk
    serveralias newdomain.com
    serveralias localhost

    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"

    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"> 
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none 
    </Directory> 

    #JkOptions     +ForwardURICompatUnparsed
    ProxyRequests off
    JkMount /* ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone offer me any pointers ?  I have browsed a fair few similar questions but not found anything conclusive and next time I have the opportunity to bring the server down I'm hoping to have something definite to try rather than hacking about !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want from **olddomain.com -> newdomain.com** 
Leave these settings on your apache.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName olddomain.com
ServerAlias newdomain.com

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

If you want from **newdomain.com -> olddomain.com**
Leave these settings on your apache.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName newdomain.com
ServerAlias olddomain.com

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.olddomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Also in your DNS settings an `A Record` is enough for your new domain. All you have to do is to point it to your server.

Make sure to backup your current configuration before doing these changes. Since you're live, I couldn't test this for you but it should work.

Comment: Okay thanks.  That broadly worked.  Oddly although the redirecty worked when I added the above to the vhosts file, the actual site stopped working.  When I used the broad suggested config but kept the redirect with the if statement it works.  Many thanks!

Comment: Good to know, So the it only worked when you kept your vhost config file with my rewriteengine code? If so could you reproduce the error and give the apache log? I'm curious to see where it failed. Anyways glad I could help you

Comment: Sorry I'll try and do this today.  I put your code in the vhost  file.  Pretty sure I still need this (honestly can't remember if it is for forwarding to Tomcat or because we are doing some very basic load balancing.  It was failing until I put the rewrite code back into the main httpd.conf file.

Comment: Just keep me updated, if you're still in troubles just comment here again and i'll try to help you out